# Doctrine & ManyToOne Foreign key issue

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, many-to-one

I'm trying to create a relation between a `Language` entity and a `User` entity, one language has many users, but a user has one language.
So I created this relation as follow :

In User.php:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $language;
```

In Language.php

```
/**
 * @var ArrayCollection
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="language")
 */
private $users;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

I've just followed the Doctrine mapping documentation to create these lines of code.

I've created the schema with `doctrine:schema:create command line,` and when I try to validate it, it says :

> [ERROR] The database schema is not in sync with the current mapping
> file.

So I tried a `doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` to see what's the cause of the problem :

```
ALTER TABLE user CHANGE language_id language_id INT DEFAULT NULL;
```

What could be the problem because I am very confused?

Comment: i can't understand your problem, you must update your schema after modify your entities.
but! i have a problem reading your relation.
it's no sense relation, a user can know many language and a language must be known from many users.
it's a many to many relation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default ManyToOne relations are nullable. The "dump sql" shows that this relation is currently not nullable in your database. I don't know if it has to but to make it non nullable you have to update your User entity mapping on the language property as follow :

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language", inversedBy="users")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, name="language_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $language;
```